# Compare Objects within array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have one array with objects in it. Say:

```
[{id: 0, fight: true}, {id: 1, fight: false}, {id: 2, fight: true}, {id: 3, fight: false}, {id: 4, fight: true}, {id: 5, fight: false}, {id: 6, fight: false}, {id: 7, fight: false}]
```

I want to take every two objects within the array that have the same value (such as object.fight). I want to then pass those objects into a function where I can do other things with them. I want to be sure that once an element of the array has been compared, that it is not compared again. In this case, I would get the first and third object passed into my function. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you explain with an example?

Comment: That's not the correct syntax for object properties. The `key: value`, not `key = value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need nested `for` loops:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (var j = i+1; j < array.length; j++) {
        func(array[i], array[j]);
    }
}
```

Starting the inner loop at `i+1` prevents calling the function with the same pair of elements in a different order.